# PHP Loop with Conditional Statement for CURL Execution

Tags: php, if-statement, curl, while-loop, do-while

I am using 2 functions to execute a CURL. The first function retrieves and store a token while the other executes the order with the token stored.

I am using file_put_contents and file_get_contents to store and retrieve the token.

Function A:

```
function functionA() {
$ch = curl_init();

$url_token = $this->config['TOKEN'];
$id = $this->config['ID'];
$secret = $this->config['SECRET'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"client_id\": \"$id\",
  \"client_secret\": \"$secret\",
  \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);
$file = 'key.txt';
$token = $json['access_token'];

file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/key.txt', $token, LOCK_EX);

//return $token;
}
```

Function B:

```
$file = './modules/custommodule/key.txt';
$retrieved_token = file_get_contents($file);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_order);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"service_type\": \"xxx\",
  \"service_level\": \"xxx\",
  \"requested_tracking_number\": \"xxx\",
  \"reference\": {
    \"merchant_order_number\": \"xxx\"
  },
  \"from\": {
    \"name\": \"xxx\",
    \"phone_number\": \"xxx\",
    \"email\": \"xxx\",
    \"address\": {
      \"address1\": \"xxx\",
      \"address2\": \"xxx\",
      \"area\": \"xxx\",
      \"city\": \"xxx\",
      \"state\": \"xxx\",
      \"country\": \"xxx\",
      \"postcode\": \"xxx\"
    }
  },
  \"to\": {
    \"name\": \"xxx\",
    \"phone_number\": \"xxx\",
    \"email\": \"xxx\",
    \"address\": {
      \"address1\": \"xxx\",
      \"address2\": \"xxx\",
      \"area\": \"xxx\",
      \"city\": \"xxx\",
      \"state\": \"xxx\",
      \"country\": \"xxx\",
      \"postcode\": \"xxx\"
    }
  },
  \"parcel_job\": {
    \"pickup_instruction\": \"xxx\",
    \"delivery_instruction\": \"xxx\",
    \"delivery_start_date\": \"xxx\",
    \"delivery_timeslot\": {
      \"start_time\": \"xxx\",
      \"end_time\": \"xxx\",
      \"timezone\": \"xxx\"
    },
    \"dimensions\": {
      \"size\": \"xxx\"
    }
  }
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer $retrieved_token"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpcode === 401) {
    functionA();
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/response.txt', $response, LOCK_EX);
file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/results.txt', $httpcode, LOCK_EX);
```

As you can see, I will need to re-run Function A before initiating Function B if the token has expired. I have used the status 401 that I store as a variable $httpcode.

I am unsure how to re-run Function B upon getting the new/refreshed token. Which loop and condition should I be implementing to achieve this?

Can anyone point this out? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to store the expiration period of your token so you can check your token at your side before calling the function B. If the token is expired, you will request a new token then call the function B. Assuming that the API authorization state will give you the expiration period

Comment: I will need to check if I am able to get the information. Let me see what information I can dig when I retrieve the token.

Comment: Agreed, whilst its good to keep track of when the token expires and refresh it preemptively, the app should also handle a 401/403 when performing requests.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic concept at re-try framework, provided you can keep a cache of the last time you fetched the token.

Refactor with the status you need to determine success/failure

```
function CurlRequestUsingTokenWithRetry( $curRequest, $previousToken )
{

   $token = $previousToken;

   $retries = 10;

   while( $retries > 0 )
   {

      $result = PerformTheCurlRequest( $curRequest, $token );

      if( $resultStatusCode == 401 )
      {
        $token = GetNewToken();
        if( !$token )
        {
          throw new Exception('getting new token failed');
        }
      }
      elseif( $resultStatusCode == 403 )
      {
        throw new Exception('oh no you are blocked');
      }
      else
      {
        return $reuslt;
      }

      $retries--;

   }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Scuzzy, I am able to fetch the token as I store it in key.txt everytime I run functionA(). For your "if" clause status 401, may I know how do you return to perform $result = PerformTheCurlRequest( $curRequest, $token ); after getting a new token?

Comment: That's upto you to extend the concept with, either put the curl code in-line right there, or create a helper function. My goal was to demonstrate a simple structure while loop to allow you to re-try requests after fetching a new token based on the curl request failing. I recently implemented this structure in a project and it's proving simple but effective.

Comment: Yeap, but I am not getting the part where you re-run the code after if( $resultStatusCode == 401 )
      {
        $token = GetNewToken();
      }. Is it by the retries--; you input?

Comment: Here's an example of the while loop :) `$retries = 10; while( $retries > 0 ) { echo 'R'; $retries--; }` in the above the "echo" is replaced with work that either allows the while loop to keep looping, or returns or throws an exception breaking the loop. only the 401 will cause the while loop to continue by not breaking out of it. Note that were `$token` is refreshed, there is no break out of the loop.

Comment: $retries is actually just a backup control mechanism. The loop should probably be broken if `$token` fails to get.

Comment: So I need to add while loop before the start of Function B and the conditions as stated? I have tested and it loops several times.... will it send the CURL execution several times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161672/discussion-between-enthu-and-scuzzy).